# have line break in li item when it crosses specified width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an autosuggest dropdown, which has `<ul>` `<li>` tags to display suggestions list. Some items in suggestion list which are held within `<li>` are long and cross the width of the dropdown.

How can I break text in `<li>` to display in 2 lines when it crosses the dropdow width?

Comment: We can't help without seeing your code - jsFiddle would be good.

Comment: question depends on the css being used and we can't see any of that

Comment: <a> tag in <li> had css property white-space set to nowrap, which stopped the word wrap. Problem solved by setting property value to normal. Thanks for comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just put it inside an element with a fixed `width` or give the `ul` the desired width. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lsk10gg/.